# Tecnica two-pointers en java para hacer de reverso un string

Tags: java, algoritmos

Me encuentro realizando este siguiente ejercicio, donde el problema es que te dan un string y debes de ponerlo alrevez.

Entrada
String s = "hello world"
Salida
String reversed = "world hello"

tengo esto,

```
 String[] newWord = words. Trim().split("");


        for (int i = 0, j = newWord.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
                String temp = newWord[i];
                newWord[i] = newWord[j];
                newWord[j] = temp;
        }

        String reversedString = String.join("", newWord);

         return reversedString;
    }
```

mi resultado es: dlroW olleH

no tengo la minimaidea de que esta mal,

me podrian guiar en que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en `split("")` (se pasa una cadena vacía como token), al hacerlo así va a partir la cadena en caracteres y no en palabras separadas por espacios. Debería ser así: `split(" ");`

De igual forma con el `join` se debe pasar un espacio en blanco y no una cadena vacía:

```
  String words = "Hello World";
  String[] newWord = words.trim().split(" "); // espacio en blanco
    for (int i = 0, j = newWord.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
            String temp = newWord[i];
            newWord[i] = newWord[j];
            newWord[j] = temp;
    }

  String reversedString = String.join(" ", newWord); // espacio en blanco
  System.out.println(reversedString);
```

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!!

Comment: estamos agradecidos!!! entonces si quiero que sea "h" "o" "l" "a" en split debe ir splirt("") y si quiero, hola mundo, en split debe ser split(" ")... correcto??

Comment: Sí, es correcto.